# with the highs of success and fame followed by the lows of drug addiction and depression

Tags: grammar

Eric writes about the roller coaster of rock and roll, *with* **the highs of success and fame followed by the lows of drug addiction and depression**.

---

Is the bold part a noun phrase and the object of "*with*"?

Comment: Both ***the highs of success and fame*** and ***the lows of drug addiction and depression*** are noun phrases WITHIN the ***adverbial*** clause starting with ***with***. But both of those noun phrases *themselves* contain "noun phrases", so it's not obvious to me that "noun" is a useful concept here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does "*with*" mean "in which"? (which refers to "the roller coaster of rock and roll")

Comment: *Very* approximately, yes. But if you change ***with*** to ***in which***, you've changed the syntactic construction, and it becomes necessary to include ***are*** after ***success and fame***. And I can't think of an example offhand, but there are probably contexts that look the same as your example *to you*, but which either don't permit that substitution, OR it might significantly change the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a reasonable analysis. The bold part of the example is a valid noun phrase.  This sentence probably can be parsed or bracketed in more than one way.  You could take the object of "with" to be "the highs and lows of fame". and "followed by ..." to be a separate participle phrase.

But I don't detect any real difference in meaning between the two ways of parsing the sentences. So this is one of those cases of angels dancing on pinheads. The choice of bracketing doesn't seem to affect meaning, so I'll not worry about it too much.